# I'm getting an error with the gas limit definition when deploying a smart contract using CodePromise

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, pallet-contracts

- Problem

  - The following program does not work with pallet-contract "polkadot-v0.9.29".
  - "polkadot-v0.9.27" in pallet-contract works as expected.
  - Anyone know how to get around this issue?
- Source Code

```js
  const gasLimit = 100000 * 1000000;
  const storageDepositLimit = null;

  const deployContract = async () => {
    const { web3FromSource } = await import("@polkadot/extension-dapp");
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider(blockchainUrl);
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
    const contractWasm = contract_file.source.wasm;
    const code = new CodePromise(api, abi, contractWasm);
    const initValue = false;
    const performingAccount = accounts[0];
    const injector = await web3FromSource(performingAccount.meta.source);
    
    const tx = code.tx.new({ value:0, gasLimit:gasLimit,storageDepositLimit }, initValue);
```

- I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding contracts.instantiateWithCode:: Struct: failed on args: {"value":"Compact<u128>","gas_limit":"Compact<FrameSupportWeightsWeightV2Weight>","storage_deposit_limit":"Option<Compact<u128>>","code":"Bytes","data":"Bytes","salt":"Bytes"}:: Struct: failed on gas_limit: Compact<FrameSupportWeightsWeightV2Weight>:: Struct: Cannot decode value 100000000000 (typeof number), expected an input object, map or array
```

Somebody please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using "8.4.1" from "polkadot/api-contract". I solved it by just upgrading to the latest "9.6.1".